# Is it compulsory to use <Route> only inside of App.js? throwing error like "Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Is it compulsory to use the  of react-router in the App.js?

I'm trying to use the react router in my app and I'm stuck at something.

I have a component called ProductList.jsx. In that component I want to define the path of  Cart.jsx component using .  I definitely want to define path of the Cart.jsx inside of ProductList.jsx because it does take some props from the ProductList.jsx.

When I tried to define the path it throws an error like "Error: Invariant failed: You should not use `<Link>` outside a `<Router>`"

Including the code below

**App.jsx**

```
import Home from "./pages/Home";

const App = () => {
  
  return (
  <>
        <Home />
        </>
  )
};
export default App
```

**Home.jsx**

```
const Home = () => {
  return (
 
    <div>
      
      <Navbar />
      <Slider/>
      <Categories/> 
      <PopularProducts/>
      <ProductList/>
      <Footer/>
      
    </div>
  
  );
};
```

**ProductList.jsx**

```
const ProductList = () => {
  const [mobileOpen, setMobileOpen] = useState(false);
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const [cart, setCart] = useState({});
  const [order, setOrder] = useState({});
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');

  const fetchProducts = async () => {
    const { data } = await commerce.products.list();

    setProducts(data);
  };

  const fetchCart = async () => {
    setCart(await commerce.cart.retrieve());
  };

  const handleAddToCart = async (productId, quantity) => {
    const item = await commerce.cart.add(productId, quantity);

    setCart(item.cart);
  };

  const handleUpdateCartQty = async (lineItemId, quantity) => {
    const response = await commerce.cart.update(lineItemId, { quantity });

    setCart(response.cart);
  };

  const handleRemoveFromCart = async (lineItemId) => {
    const response = await commerce.cart.remove(lineItemId);

    setCart(response.cart);
  };

  const handleEmptyCart = async () => {
    const response = await commerce.cart.empty();

    setCart(response.cart);
  };

  const refreshCart = async () => {
    const newCart = await commerce.cart.refresh();

    setCart(newCart);
  };

  const handleCaptureCheckout = async (checkoutTokenId, newOrder) => {
    try {
      const incomingOrder = await commerce.checkout.capture(checkoutTokenId, newOrder);

      setOrder(incomingOrder);

      refreshCart();
    } catch (error) {
      setErrorMessage(error.data.error.message);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchProducts();
    fetchCart();
  }, []);

  const handleDrawerToggle = () => setMobileOpen(!mobileOpen);
  const user= ''


  return (
    <Container>
      <Navbar />
      <Router>
      <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
        <CssBaseline />
        
        <Switch>
        
      <Route path="/login" >
        {user ? <Redirect to="/"/> :  <Login/> }
      </Route>
      <Route path="/register" >
        <Register />
      </Route>
          <Route path="/products">
            <Products products={products} onAddToCart={handleAddToCart} handleUpdateCartQty />
            <Footer/>
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/cart">
            <Cart cart={cart} onUpdateCartQty={handleUpdateCartQty} onRemoveFromCart={handleRemoveFromCart} onEmptyCart={handleEmptyCart} />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/checkout">
            <Checkout cart={cart} order={order} onCaptureCheckout={handleCaptureCheckout} error={errorMessage} />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
    <Cart cart={cart} onUpdateCartQty={handleUpdateCartQty} onRemoveFromCart={handleRemoveFromCart} onEmptyCart={handleEmptyCart} />
      <Footer/>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default ProductList;
```

Comment: Please proof read your question before posting, there's a lot of mistakes, looks like you've missed certain words.

Comment: Don't worry about the code . I just wanna know if it is okay to define path in a component other than App.js

Comment: You're probably rendering a `<Link>` in your `<Navbar>` (or one of the other components next to the product list)? The problem is that it doesn't work outside the `<Router>` context, but you use that only inside the `<ProductList>`.

Comment: The error message seems to be quite clear. Notice it talks about `<Router>`, not about `<Route>`! What's wrong with putting the router in the `<App>`?

Comment: here is the github link for complete code : https://github.com/anascsk/audiobae

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Error: Invariant failed: You should not use `<Link>` outside a
> `<Router>`"

It's compulsory to render all `Link`, `Switch`, and `Route` components ***within*** a routing context. From your snippet I don't see a `Router` rendered until well into the `ProductList` component. I suspect the "link outside a router" issue is from your `Navbar` component being outside the `Router` component.

Move the `Router` to wrap the entire app. Remove all other extraneous routers, if there are any. You need only one single router to provide a routing context to the entire app.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Home />
    </Router>
  )
};
```

...

```
const ProductList = () => {
  ...

  return (
    <Container>
      <Navbar />
      <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
        <CssBaseline />
        
        <Switch>
          ... routes ...
        </Switch>
      </div>
      ...
    </Container>
  );
};
```

Comment: Even though I've tried those methods still does not worked for me. Only component which i added on App.jsx is rendered as home page. I can't access any paths like /products or /cart.   here is the github link for complete code https://github.com/anascsk/audiobae

Comment: @AnnzRocky The `ProductList` component appears to be the component rendering any routes, and yet nothing in your app is rendering `ProductList`. Either way, you should probably move your routes higher up in the ReactTree, probably the `App` component so it handles the switch and routing to render the home, login, registration, product, etc... pages. Does this make sense?

Comment: Alright. But is there any way to set route path for `Cart` component in `ProductList` component because it does take props from `ProductList`.

Comment: @AnnzRocky Sure, you've options. You could render the `ProductList` on a root `"/products"` path and then render additional nested routes from `ProductList` and pass the props to the routed components. You could also implement global app state (i.e. redux) and dispatch actions and select from state, all without the need to pass callbacks around in props.These are only a couple examples.